# Get current TabLayout tab position

Tags: android, sqlite, android-tabs

I have an Android app with a `ViewPager` and a `TabLayout` to create tabs, and I want to store data from the tabs in the database with the position or index of the tab.

I have a table called `DATA` and a column called `tabno`, and I want to store the tab associated with the data, but I am having trouble getting the position/index of the tab to save with the data in the database.

Comment: i get it but when i changed tab no 1 to tow its giving correct position but when i am changing back from tab 2 to 1 its giving some garbage value i think

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Trying to be more legible, state the context up front.